# Need help deploying react application with netlify

Tags: reactjs, deployment, web-deployment, netlify

Not familiar with how to use netlify. Im trying to deploy this app

https://github.com/Rshauneb/real-estate

my build command is:
npm run watch

but every time I try to deploy my site I keep getting this error.

"failed during stage 'building site'"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Mimic what Netlify is doing in the build using their build bot.

- Clone your project into a clean directory from GitHub
- `npm install`
- `npm run watch`

If you do not get an error, you may have a global command or setting that does not get set on Netlify. Without more information, this is the only answer possible.

Here is the error I found when I did the above:
[image]

---

#### Problem #2

Watch is a command for local development, so you should **not be using** `npm run watch` as a build command on Netlify. You will need to run the command to build your site into a directory for deploy and use that directory for your "Deploy directory".